# Como resolver o erro: "O aplicativo XXXX parou"?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma aplicação na linguagem **C#** que desenvolve um aplicativo para android (utilizando o xamarin).
A aplicação funciona normalmente para android das versões 2, 3, 4 e 5. Porém, utilizando um aparelho com **android 6** (marshmallow), o aplicativo é carregado mas aleatoriamente trava exibindo a seguinte mensagem na tela do aparelho: **"O aplicativo XXXXX parou"** (XXXXX é o nome da minha aplicação).

Quando ocorre essa mensagem, no **Visual Studio** é lançada a seguinte exceção:

> Debugger lost connection to the running application. Likely this means
>   the application terminated unexpectedly.
>
> More details can usually be found in the device's debug log:
>
> http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log
>
> More Details:
>
> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: Exceção do
>   tipo 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' foi acionada.    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive(CommandSet command_set,
>   Int32 command, PacketWriter packet)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Object_GetInfo(Int64 id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.GetObject[T](Int64 id, Int64
>   domain_id, Int64 type_id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.GetObject[T](Int64 id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event.get_Thread()    em
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleThreadStartEvents(ThreadStartEvent[]
>   events)    em
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es)
>   em Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()

Já tentei baixar a API 23, tentei atualizar o JDK, tentei alterar o "target" no arquivo "manifest". Porém não obtive sucesso.
Alguém sabe como solucionar esse problema?

Desde já obrigada.

Comment: O aplicativo talvez, eu digo talvez, esteja está travando porque você tem que tratar as questões de permissão. É necessário controlar as permissões do seu app no Android 6.0 e superior. Leia aqui: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Cara tenho problema parecido, no modo debugger funciona normal, já no release apresento o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

É difícil conseguir te ajudar, sem ao menos saber qual versão de xamarin você usa. Na internet há varios relatos de usuários sofrendo do mesmo problema, mas em versôes mais antigas do que a atual.

Recomendo você a atualizar o seu xamarin e efetuar uma instalação a limpo.

(Queria que essa 'resposta' fosse um comentário, pois não solucionou o problema diretamente, mas não tenho reputação suficiente nos foruns StackOverflow PT.)

Comment: Eu também passei por isso, como muitos outros, digo sobre o comentário, mas é necessário seguir as regras uma vez que tenha aceitado as politicas de uso do site. Desta forma algumas pessoas, talvez, eu digo talvez, vão sinalizar esta resposta como "não é uma resposta"

Comment: Obrigada pelo retorno.

Atualmente está:
Versão Xamarin: 3.9.547.0 
Versão Xamarin.Android: 4.20.2.1

Porém fiz um teste utilizando o Xamarin 4.2 e o erro continua...